# Posting data when text input is not empty PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have a table that gives me 3 columns, product code, product name and a checkbox.

It currently works where it basically will post any products that have been checked, but i want to change the functionality to a text box rather than checkbox, and to only post data that has something in the text box, I have been tinkering with it to no avail.

This is my table:

```
<form id="frm-example" action="price-quote.php" method="POST">                    
<table id="datatable-price" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Add to quote</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while($res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($def, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
            <tr>                                
                <td><?php echo $res['ItemCode']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res['ItemName']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $res['ItemCode'];?>"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?> 
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Quote"></input>
</form>
```

This is the javascript to go with it:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
     var table = $('#datatable-price').DataTable({
     });

     // Handle click on "Select all" control
     $('#datatable-price-select-all').on('click', function(){
        // Get all rows with search applied
        var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
        // Check/uncheck checkboxes for all rows in the table
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
     });

     // Handle click on checkbox to set state of "Select all" control
     $('#datatable-price tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
        // If checkbox is not checked
        if(!this.checked){
           var el = $('#datatable-price-select-all').get(0);
           // If "Select all" control is checked and has 'indeterminate' property
           if(el && el.checked && ('indeterminate' in el)){
              // Set visual state of "Select all" control 
              // as 'indeterminate'
              el.indeterminate = true;
           }
        }
     });

     // Handle form submission event
     $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
        var form = this;

        // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
        table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
           // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
           if(!$.contains(document, this)){
              // If checkbox is checked
              if(this.checked){
                 // Create a hidden element 
                 $(form).append(
                    $('<input>')
                       .attr('type', 'hidden')
                       .attr('name', this.name)
                       .val(this.value)
                 );
              }
           } 
        });
     });

  });
</script>
```

And this is my page where it posts too:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check){
        $abc = "SELECT ItemCode, ItemName 
                FROM OITM 
                WHERE ItemCode = '$check' 
                ORDER BY ItemName";
        $def = sqlsrv_query($sapconn, $abc);
        $res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($def, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
        $prodCode = $res['ItemCode'];
        $prodName = $res['ItemName'];

        echo "
            <tr>                                
                <td>$prodCode</td>
                <td>$prodName</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone adapt this to submit with text in a text box rather than the check box. It would be great, greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did not get the question. you will change checkboxes to textboxes, and if they are filled you will submit them. am i right ?

Comment: That is the required functionality yes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what do you wanna do that but there are many ways to do.

First, you can change the value of checkboxes to do multi-valuable field (not recommended). Works.

Something like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $res['ItemCode'];?>|<?php echo $res['ItemName'];?>"></input>
```

In PHP you get and split value.

---

Second, you can add hidden fields. When checkbox marked you create dynamically hidden with value and text desirable.

---

You can continue using checkbox passing codes. After post you use **implode**.
You need to do that because you can receive more than 1 item checked.

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $in = implode(",",$_POST['checkbox']);

    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check){
        $abc = "SELECT ItemCode, ItemName FROM OITM WHERE ItemCode in ('. $in . ') ORDER BY ItemName";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to give an answer, but i already have it working off a checkbox, I wanted to change that to an input text and submit if the field has been filled in.

Comment: HI PHPNewbie, great! If need help, shout!

Comment: Yeah if you could help that would be great!

Comment: Are you available for some help?

Comment: Hi PHPNewbie maybe yes. What do you need?

Comment: I need to adapt the code above, to submit the data that has been entered into an input text rather than a checking a check box

Comment: Hi @PHPNewbie I added other piece of code to you see. You didn't need change your code. You can submit items checked and using to construct your query after submit.

Comment: Thanks, i will have a look at this.